# Can't answer a protected question despite having sufficient reputation

Tags: bug, answers, protected-questions

The question [Apple A1277 USB ethernet adapter not working on MacBook Air](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127840/apple-a1277-usb-ethernet-adapter-not-working-on-macbook-air) requires a reputation of 10 to post an answer. My account has a reputation of 106, through (mostly) the magic cross-site Stack Exchange bonus, but I can't post an answer.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Protected questions require 10 reputation to have been **earned on the site itself**, thus this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The 100 reputation association bonus is purposefully removed from the calculation used to determine if you have sufficient reputation to answer a protected question, and as such you have 6 reputation which is below the 10 threshold.

If you found the protected question notice confusing, feel free to upvote this Meta.SE feature request to [change the phrasing of the protected question post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati).

I went to upvote your question so you'd have enough reputation, but I've already done that!